# FindViewByID and Xamarin.Forms.Listview not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am just learning the basics of Xamarin.Android and have successfully got basic two Activity pages up and running. I have added a Xamarin.Forms.ListView to my second page and set up a variable in my .cs file so I can access it and bind it to a List of a class object.

I started using an Android.Widget.ListView, but I read that the Xamarin.Forms.Listview was the correct one to use for setting a .ItemsSource.

The FindViewByID doesn't work on Xamarin.Forms.ListView however.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;

using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Landfill_App
{
    [Activity(Label = "Vehicle Reg")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {

//Variable to hold the Xamarin.Forms.ListView
        ListView mainList;

//Create new collection that you can bind to the ListView
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<VehicleReg> Regs = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<VehicleReg>();

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);


            mainList = FindViewById<Xamarin.Forms.ListView>(Resource.Id.mainlistview);
            //mainList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
            mainList.ItemsSource = Regs;

//Add a new class object 'VehicleReg' to the Regs collection
            Regs.Add(new VehicleReg()
            {
                Reg = "GHJ6786",
                Weight = 250.56M

            });

        }
```

My XML from the Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp">
    <Xamarin.Forms.ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/mainlistview"/>

  <TextView
    android:text="string/Layout1Activity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="BACK"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
       android:onClick="GoBack"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to bind a List of(MyClass) to the ListView.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried in vain to search google, but it's mind blowing the amount of information on this subject and google seems to often return results that aren't related to what you searched.

Comment: ,According to your description, you want to use Xamarin.Forms.ListView in android? Why don't you use Android.Widget.ListView? I think you should use Android.Widget.ListView in xamarin.android, Xamarin.Forms.ListView should be used in Xamarin.Form project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Android.Widget.Listview doesn't have an ItemsSource to bind a list of class objects to. Also, does that mean x:Name doesn't work in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: I think so. You can use Adapter to feed Android.Widget,ListView with data  contained in row  views.

Comment: If you have solved your issue, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I think you should use Android.Widget.ListView in xamarin.android, Xamarin.Forms.ListView should be used in Xamarin.Form project.

You can use Adapter to feed Android.Widget.ListView with data contained in row views.

Here is the article about using Android.Widget.ListView:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix and match Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Forms which in my opinion is not a best way. You should either use Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms.

[You can follow this tutorial for Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)

[Sample code is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithlistview/)

Comment: Yeah, I can see now that you should do this (I'm only working on Xamarin.Android. I've only been learning for a week and a half and it seems to be a very broad subject and there is a lot to go through. Creating a ListView in Android, vs c#/vb.net is so different. I'll get there!